# Hooks vs Raw Input API

Tags: winapi, hook

I have currently created some area of my app by using hooks (for getting pressed keys and mouse clicks), but at that time I didn't know completely about Raw Input API. Is there any point to change the hooking system into Raw Input API? What are the advantages/disadvantages for using Raw Input API over hooks and vice versa? Any detailed answer?

Comment: Hooks are expensive. Avoid them if there is a more efficient alternative.

Comment: Hooks will also cause a lot of anti-virus programs to flag your app.